# How can I pass data into app.blade.php with Eloquent in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am making navbar menu. I want to fetch data from database and display here. Now how can I do that ? Is it possible without using route?

Comment: Are you getting the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to App/Providers/AppServiceProvider

```
  <?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use DB;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
       View::share('categories', DB::select('select * from categories')); 
    }
}
```

and you can get your datas

```
@foreach($categories as list)

<ul>
<li> {{$list->name}} </li>
<ul>

@endforeach
```

I hope it helps you! good luck!